# Unit testing NestJS Observable Http Retry

Tags: rxjs, jestjs, nestjs

I'm making a request to a 3rd party API via NestJS's built in HttpService. I'm trying to simulate a scenario where the initial call to one of this api's endpoints might return an empty array on the first try. I'd like to use RxJS's `retryWhen` to hit the api again after a delay of 1 second. I'm currently unable to get the unit test to mock the second response however:

```
it('Retries view account status if needed', (done) => {
    jest.spyOn(httpService, 'post')
      .mockReturnValueOnce(of(failView)) // mock gets stuck on returning this value
      .mockReturnValueOnce(of(successfulView));
    const accountId = '0812081208';
    const batchNo = '39cba402-bfa9-424c-b265-1c98204df7ea';
    const response =client.viewAccountStatus(accountId, batchNo);
    response.subscribe(
      data => {
        expect(data[0].accountNo)
          .toBe('0812081208');
        expect(data[0].companyName)
          .toBe('Some company name');
        done();
      },
    )
  });
```

My implementation is:

```
viewAccountStatus(accountId: string, batchNo: string): Observable<any> {
    const verificationRequest = new VerificationRequest();
    verificationRequest.accountNo = accountId;
    verificationRequest.batchNo = batchNo;


    this.logger.debug(`Calling 3rd party service with batchNo: ${batchNo}`);

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    const response = this.httpService.post(url, verificationRequest, config)
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          console.log(res.data); // always empty
          if (res.status >= 400) {
            throw new HttpException(res.statusText, res.status);
          }

          if (!res.data.length) {
            this.logger.debug('Response was empty');
            throw new HttpException('Account not found', 404);
          }

          return res.data;
        }),
        retryWhen(errors => {
          this.logger.debug(`Retrying accountId: ${accountId}`);
          // It's entirely possible the first call will return an empty array
          // So we retry with a backoff
          return errors.pipe(
            delayWhen(() => timer(1000)),
            take(1),
          );
        }),
      );

    return response;
  }
```

When logging from inside the initial map, I can see that the array is always empty. It's as if the second mocked value never happens. Perhaps I also have a solid misunderstanding of how observables work and I should somehow be trying to assert against the SECOND value that gets emitted? Regardless, when the observable retries, we should be seeing that second mocked value, right?

I'm also getting

```
: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
```

On each run... so I'm guessing I'm not calling `done()` in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `retryWhen(notifier)` will resubscribe to the same source when its `notifier` emits.

Meaning that if you have

```js
new Observable(s => {
  s.next(1);
  s.next(2);

  s.error(new Error('err!'));
}).pipe(
  retryWhen(/* ... */)
)
```

The callback will be invoked every time the source is re-subscribed. In your example, it will call the logic which is responsible for sending the request, but it won't call the `post` method again.

The source could be thought of as the `Observable`'s callback: `s => { ... }`.

What I think you'll have to do is to conditionally choose the source, based on whether the error took place or not.

Maybe you could use [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname):

```js
let hasErr = false;

jest.spyOn(httpService, 'post')
  .mockImplementation(
    () => hasErr ? of(successView) : (hasErr = true, of(failView))
  )
```

### Edit

I think the above does not do anything different, where's what I think `mockImplementation` should look like:

```js
let err = false;

mockImplementation(
 () => new Observable(s => {
   if (err) { 
     s.next(success) 
   } 
   else { 
    err = true;
    s.next(fail) 
   } 
 })
)
```

Comment: I think it's definitely in the "resubscribe" part. With that said, POST will have to be called again in real life, so I'd need to find some way to make that happen. I did try what you suggested, but it has the same effect as calling `.mockReturnValueOnce()`. The implementation does run multiple times, it just never gets to that second "successfulView". Since I can't prove this would do what I think it should do, I can't ship this unfortunately. I'm going to revert to a Promise-based solution and learn maybe learn more about Observables.

Comment: Before you do that, try this: `mockImplementation(() => new Observable(s => {  if (err) { s.next(success) } else { err = true; s.next(fail) }  }))`.

Comment: That passes. My concern is that it actually doesn't call POST again. In a real scenario, I'd want to POST/retry the endpoint. I certainly appreciate your answer as it helps me understand just a bit more. The secret really is in the `next()`

Comment: Imagine that `http.post` simply returns `new Observable(s => fetch(...)then(...).then(r => s.next(r)))`. The observable's callback is the **source**. `retryWhen` will re-subscribe to that stream... so that's why the `post` method is not called again. In a real scenario, although it doesn't call the method again, it re-invokes the logic that was created by that method, so it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: Also, if you'd like to read more about the `HttpClientModule` and how it works, you could check out [this article](https://indepth.dev/exploring-the-httpclientmodule-in-angular/).

Comment: Ok, now that makes sense. So this test actually DOES simulate what would happen in a real world scenario. Thanks for the article linlk!